# full joining 3 tables and ordering by one

Tags: mysql

### **This is giving me a headache. I'll try to give a good example based on a database of user posts.**

**Table1** has the BODY of the post along with a unique POSTID and USERNAME of the author.

**Table2** carries the number of "likes" a post has (LIKES) referenced by POSTID (which matches the postid from Table1).

Users are allowed to "share" other people's posts on their page. So...

**Table3** carries the POSTID of the shared post along with the USERNAME of the user sharing it.

On the user's page you want to display a listing of his posts along with the posts he wants to share. So we need to grab all of the POSTIDs of the posts from table1 where he is the USERNAME and add to that all the POSTIDs from table3 where he is the USERNAME, and then order all of the POSTIDs by the number of LIKES in table2.

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT postid 
FROM posts_views_likes 
LEFT JOIN posts USING (postid) 
LEFT JOIN shared_posts USING (postid) 
WHERE posts.username = 'abbsmalone' 
UNION 
SELECT postid 
FROM posts_views_likes 
LEFT JOIN posts USING (postid) 
LEFT JOIN shared_posts USING (postid) 
WHERE shared_posts.username = 'abbsmalone' 
ORDER BY posts_views_likes.likes DESC
```

I also tried...

```
SELECT postid 
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN posts_views_likes USING (postid) 
LEFT JOIN shared_posts USING (postid) 
WHERE posts.username = 'abbsmalone' 
UNION 
SELECT postid 
FROM shared_posts 
LEFT JOIN posts_views_likes USING (postid) 
LEFT JOIN posts USING (postid) 
WHERE shared_posts.username = 'abbsmalone' 
ORDER BY posts_views_likes.likes DESC
```

Obviously, that doesn't work. I keep getting an error saying  #1054 - Unknown column 'likes' in 'order clause'

I assume such a thing is possible?

UPDATE:

I also tried:

```
SELECT postid, posts_views_likes.likes 
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN posts_views_likes USING (postid) 
LEFT JOIN shared_posts USING (postid) 
WHERE posts.username = 'abbsmalone' 
UNION 
SELECT postid, posts_views_likes.likes 
FROM posts_views_likes 
LEFT JOIN posts USING (postid) 
LEFT JOIN shared_posts USING (postid) 
WHERE shared_posts.username = 'abbsmalone' 
UNION 
SELECT postid, posts_views_likes.likes 
FROM shared_posts 
LEFT JOIN posts_views_likes USING (postid) 
LEFT JOIN posts USING (postid) 
WHERE posts.username = 'abbsmalone' OR shared_posts.username = 'abbsmalone' 
ORDER BY posts_views_likes.likes DESC
```

But I get the same error.

UPDATE FIXED:

I finally figured it out and it was a lot easier than I was trying to make it.

```
SELECT postid, posts_views_likes.ratio, posts.username 
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN posts_views_likes USING (postid) 
LEFT JOIN shared_posts USING (postid) 
WHERE posts.username = 'abbsmalone' 
OR shared_posts.username = 'abbsmalone' 
ORDER BY posts_views_likes.ratio DESC
```

Comment: you are only selecting "postid" ... you are then attempting to order by "likes"

Comment: Does the "likes" column even exist in the "posts_views_likes" table?

Comment: Yes it does exist in the table

Comment: a UNION must have the same number of columns in each of the SELECT statements.

Comment: I edited the update so that there are the same number of columns. I still get the same error as before saying likes doesn't exist. :(

Answer (score 0):

To have your ONE `order` clause sort the results of the union, you have to write the queries as

```
(SELECT ...)
UNION ALL
(SELECT ...)
ORDER BY ...
```

as per [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) (search for `to sort or limit the entire`).

And as per the docs, you can't use a table name to refer to fields in the query results. you'll have to provide aliases in the individual queries:

```
(SELECT foo AS bar ...)
UNION ALL
(SELECT baz AS bar ...)
ORDER BY bar
```